# Filling data at a particular location in a Data Table in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008

I am working with C# and Asp.Net. Is it possible to fill a particular location of a Data table.

I have a Data Table **dt**, and is contains this this kind of data. Is it possible I can add some data at particular location e.g. **column** `customer2` and **row** `Shop1`

```
 DATA  |  customer1  |  customer2  | customer3 |
-----------------------------------------------
Shop1  |             |             |           |
-----------------------------------------------
Shop2  |             |             |           |
```

Is there is a way to do this. Thanks

Comment: Is the DATA column just another field in the DataTable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can address individual cells with:

```
dt.Rows[rowIndex][columnIndex]
```

The column can be addressed by name as well:

```
dt.Rows[rowIndex]["customer2"]
```

Mind that the output is of type `Object`, so you might need to cast it to the appropriate data type if you want to read its value.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you must specify index roww and column, suggest you this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z16c79x4(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do this:

1. Filter your table to the target row
2. In the target row, write to the desired column

Code example:

```
Dim vRows() As DataRow
vRows = dt.Select("DATA='Shop1'")
vRows(0)("customer2") = "YourDataHere"
```

This way you create an array of rows which is a *reference* to the DataTable, so you can directly edit the array.

If you write this table to a database, don't forget to set up a DataAdapter and use the .Update method.