# Getting a value from datatable

Tags: c#, datatable

[image]

I have a Datatable like this.Now how can i pick the value from zones based on weight and zone.I am doing this in c#

Comment: You have "a database like this"? It looks like a grid. Please specify the question.

Comment: It is a Data table in C#

Comment: try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20148661/2416958

Comment: Its a screenshot of a datatable in preview mode in vs. Tarec. Completely plausable question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using LINQ Query : You need to use the AsEnumerable() extension for DataTable

```
    var results = from myRow in myDataTable.AsEnumerable()
                  where myRow.Field<int>("RowNo") == 1
                  select myRow;
```

AsEnumerable() returns IEnumerable. If you need to convert IEnumerable to a DataTable, use the CopyToDataTable()

Check [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10855/linq-query-on-a-datatable?rq=1)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to pick cells/rows with criteria. you need to a select clauase in your datatable. Go [Here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/datatable-select) to see some examples